# Bound for difference of largest eigenvalues of two symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\lambda(X)$ denote the largest eigenvalue of the symmetric $n\times n$ matrix $X$. Then is the following inequality true?
$$|\lambda(A)-\lambda(A-zJ)|\le n|z|$$
where $J$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with each and every entry being $1$.

I don't know any inequalities involving eigenvalues, so I am stuck. Any hints/suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$J=\mathbf{1}_n\mathbf{1}_n^T$$
with $\mathbf{1}_n:=[1,1,\cdots,1]^T$. Let $v,\bar{v}$ the (normalized) eigenvector that corresponds to the largest eigenvalue of $A$ and $A-zJ$ respectively. Then,
$$\lambda(A-zJ)=\bar{v}^*(A-zJ)\bar{v}=\bar{v}^*A\bar{v}-z\bar{v}^*\mathbf{1}_n\mathbf{1}_n^T\bar{v}\\ =\bar{v}^*A\bar{v}-z\|\mathbf{1}_n^T\bar{v}\|^2\leq \lambda(A)+|z|\|\mathbf{1}_n\|^2=\lambda(A)+n|z|\qquad\qquad(1)$$

Also,
$$\lambda(A)=v^*Av=v^*(A-zJ)v+zv^*\mathbf{1}_n\mathbf{1}_n^Tv\\ =v^*(A-zJ)v+z\|\mathbf{1}_n^Tv\|^2\leq \lambda(A-zJ)+|z|\|\mathbf{1}_n\|^2=\lambda(A-zJ)+n|z|\qquad\qquad(2)$$
From (1) we have
$$-n|z|\leq \lambda(A)-\lambda(A-zJ)\qquad\qquad(3)$$
while from (2) 
$$\lambda(A)-\lambda(A-zJ)\leq n|z|\qquad\qquad(4)$$
Combining (3), (4) the desired result 
$$|\lambda(A)-\lambda(A-zJ)|\leq n|z|$$
is obtained.